# Python : is it ok to threads read/write simultaneously to same TCP socket?

Tags: python, windows

I want to have a reader thread & a writer thread to same TCP socket.
Is it ok? Do I need to lock before accessing it ? Platform is Windows 7, CPython 2.7.4

Comment: what exact operation are you performing? just read and write on socket?

Comment: Constantly reading from one thread, and constantly writing from another

Answer (score 3):

For Unix kernel two threads one reading and other writing to a file (socket) is same as two processes doing the same. As the kernel is capable of Multiplexing  the IO you don't need to worry.

Comment: No, it is not the very same. It is a difference if two processes open a file/connection and each one has its own file descriptor or if one process opens the connection and two threads sharing the fd.
That said, you are right in that it is thread-safe, but your reason why is not the correct one.

Comment: @sukunrt No, the GIL is usually released during IO. It is thread-safe from within the kernel itself.

Comment: My platform is windows actually